# "To fill the pot to its top", would be properly describe what I mean to say?

Tags: word-choice

I'm not sure how to call this part of the pot when talking about its filling.

I have a pot and I want to describe the fact that it was full of water with no more place for water.

Does saying "*I filled the pot with water up to the top*" work in this case?

In the attached photo the part of the pot I am talking about (calling it 'top') is the part that is labeled here as 'lips'.

[image]

Comment: Try "up to the brim".

Answer (score 17):

You could say “top”, but it might be ambiguous as to whether you actually filled it all the way to the top, or if you left a small gap so that it wouldn’t overflow.

When filling a container, the word for the part labelled “lip” in the picture is **brim**.

> the top edge of a cup, bowl, glass, etc.
>
> <sub>[Oxford Learner’s Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/brim_1)</sub>

“Filled to the brim” is also used metaphorically to mean “filled to overflowing”.

You can also use **lip**, as in the diagram, and it’s also common to use the word **rim**:

> the edge of something in the shape of a circle
>
> <sub>[Oxford Learner’s Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/rim_1)</sub>

In my experience, those are more common when describing the outside of the container, though. For example you might say “the lip of my cup is chipped”, or you might salt the *rim* of a glass when making a Margarita.

Comment: But we do use ***lip*** for the actual *top edge* of a container in some contexts - particularly when thinking of it as the point of contact with one's *literal* lips, as with things like cups. [*The lip of my coffee mug is chipped.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+lip+of+the+mug+was%22)

Answer (score 6):

Ben Murphy's answer has a lot of useful context but it's worth emphasizing that the most natural way to express this is with the phrase "to the brim." "To *its* brim" is fine but not as common. Other terms like "rim" or "lip" are the more natural terms to use when you are actually talking about that part of the pot (or glass or teacup). "The brim" is really the go-to phrase for expressing maximum fullness.

There was a series of commercials for the "Brim" coffee brand with the tagline "Fill it to the rim with Brim!" They used the word "rim" because the coffee was already called "Brim", but it always seemed a little unnatural (to me) because "to the brim" is what I would normally say.